# In OAuth / OpenID Connect, does the redirect url matter for server to server API calls?

Tags: web-api, oauth2, openid

In OAuth / OpenID Connect, does the redirect url matter for server to server API calls?

I'm currently setting up Azure AD to secure our API's.  The first implementation will likely only be server to server calls.  All of the documentation shows that a redirect url is required.  What is the purpose of this url in my scenario?  Would a dummy url work just fine, or is there an endpoint I should create for the client auth flow?

Comment: I use a dummy in one place where I'm using oauth (not azure), and it works ok. I'd say just give it a shot and see what happens. Just make sure its one of your valid callback url if they require a list of valid ones.